# LemmonSlider Destroy Method

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, slider

How can I call the destroy method on LemmonSlider?

http://jquery.lemmonjuice.com/plugins/slider-variable-widths.php

I tried calling:

```
jQuery( '#abc-carousel-secondary' ).destroy();
```

after:

```
jQuery( '#abc-carousel-secondary' ).lemmonSlider({
    'infinite' : true
});
```

to initialize the slider. My goal is to swap in new li elements therefore creating the need to reinitialize the plugin.

Thoughts?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It only depends of the jquery plugin's code here. And it seems that LemmonSlider doesn't implement such a method. So your best try is first to simply initialize lemmonSlider with your default HTML. Then swap your `li` elements. Then simply reinitialize lemmonSlider with the same code.

```
jQuery(document).load(function(){

    function initSlider(){
        jQuery( '#abc-carousel-secondary' ).lemmonSlider({
            'infinite' : true
        });
    }

    // First init lemmonSlider when all images are loaded
    initSlider();

    jQuery('#swapButton').click(function(){
        // Swap your li elements
        // Then re-init lemmonSlider
        initSlider();
    });

});
```

Comment: Can't do more, sorry. Want me to remove my answer ?

Comment: I ended up modifying the lemmon slider plugin to achieve this. I will be submitting my code to the plugin author incase he wants to incorporate it.